# Maven: How can I stop the deploy plugin from logging upload progress?

Tags: maven-2, hudson, verbosity

How can I make it so Maven doesn't spam upload progress in the Hudson console?

```
Uploading: http://www.example.com/archiva/repository/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-20100804.175640-1.war
4/9430K
8/9430K
12/9430K
16/9430K
20/9430K
24/9430K
28/9430K
```

Comment: I use that plugin and I dont have that issue, do you have a specific log configuration for hudson or your project? What is the specific plugin and version that you are using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think adding the batch mode option of maven2 should do the trick.
http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-batch-option

```
mvn -B  ...
```

Another good idea is to use -fae (fail-at-end) for you hudson jobs, as it will report on more than the first error in your project.

Comment: **-B** will do the trick, however, Hudson does not call mvn with -B. It seems that this is addressed in more recent builds of Hudson: [Maven dependencies download progress indicator](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Maven-dependencies-download-progress-indicator-td3018778.html).

Comment: Another option is to add `<interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>` as a top-level element in ~/.m2/**settings.xml**. This will be a global option for your build server. See **#4** in [Maven Continuous Integration Best Practices](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2009/01/maven-continuous-integration-best-practices/#.UnqTRSSmyDc).

Comment: Thanks, the `interactiveMode` setting was unknown to me, but is obviously a better way of enforcing it across the entire CI setup.